# Checkbox & Number Fields On Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am using formidable plugin on wordpress that generates a form submission.
There will be multiple checkboxes & numbers fields just same like on https://www.mql5.com/en/market/new_product/mt4.

On that site - under "**Price**" field - by default the checkbox field is checked on value: "**Free**".
When user uncheck on that then another checkboxes will be shown on below.

So how to accomplish this purpose by using formidable on wordpress?

Btw below is html code from that link above:

```
<div class="line" style="padding-bottom: 2px;">
<div class="label">
<label for="Price">Price:</label>
</div>
<div class="field_input">
<input type="checkbox" id="priceFree" name="isFree" style="margin-top:2px;width:16px;height:16px;vertical-align:middle;" checked onclick="onPriceCheckChanged(this)" />
<label for="checkFree" style="color: #626363;vertical-align:middle;">Free</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="line" style="padding-top: 2px;">
<div class="label" style="padding-top: 2px;">

</div>
<div class="field_input">
<div style="margin-bottom:5px;">
    <div class="inputWrapper" style="width:100px;display:inline-block;*display:inline;*zoom:1;*margin-right:5px;line-height:22px;vertical-align:middle;">
        <input data-old="" id="PriceRaw" name="PriceRaw" style="text-align: right; padding-right:2px;" type="text" value="0.00" />
    </div>

    <span id="PriceAdditional" style="color:#626363;display:inline-block;*display:inline;*zoom:1;line-height:22px;vertical-align:middle;">
        USD
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkPrice" name="checkPrice" style="margin-top:2px;width:16px;height:16px;vertical-align:middle;" onclick="onPriceCheckChanged(this)" />
        <label for="checkPrice" style="color: #626363;vertical-align:middle;">for unlimited use</label>
    </span>
    <div>
        <script type='text/javascript' id='validate_PriceRaw'>/*<![CDATA[*/ mqGlobal.AddOnReady(function() {V.push(['PriceRaw',10,'Invalid price format. Please enter number',CheckProductPrice]);});mqGlobal.AddOnReady(function() {V.push(['PriceRaw',10,'Invalid price',CheckProductPriceValue]);}); /*]]>*/</script>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="margin-bottom:5px;">
    <div class="inputWrapper" style="width:100px;display:inline-block;*display:inline;*zoom:1;*margin-right:5px;line-height:22px;vertical-align:middle;">
        <input data-old="" id="Price4Raw" name="Price4Raw" style="text-align: right; padding-right:2px;" type="text" value="0.00" />
    </div>

    <span id="Price4Additional" style="color:#626363;display:inline-block;*display:inline;*zoom:1;line-height:22px;vertical-align:middle;">
        USD
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkPrice4" name="checkPrice4" style="margin-top:2px;width:16px;height:16px;vertical-align:middle;" onclick="onPriceCheckChanged(this)" />
        <label for="checkPrice4" style="color: #626363;vertical-align:middle;">1 month rent</label>
    </span>
    <div>
        <script type='text/javascript' id='validate_Price4Raw'>/*<![CDATA[*/ mqGlobal.AddOnReady(function() {V.push(['Price4Raw',10,'Invalid price format. Please enter number',CheckProductPrice]);});mqGlobal.AddOnReady(function() {V.push(['Price4Raw',10,'Invalid price',CheckProductSubscribePriceValue]);}); /*]]>*/</script>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="margin-bottom:5px;">
    <div class="inputWrapper" style="width:100px;display:inline-block;*display:inline;*zoom:1;*margin-right:5px;line-height:22px;vertical-align:middle;">
        <input data-old="" id="Price3Raw" name="Price3Raw" style="text-align: right; padding-right:2px;" type="text" value="0.00" />
    </div>

    <span id="Price3Additional" style="color:#626363;display:inline-block;*display:inline;*zoom:1;line-height:22px;vertical-align:middle;">
        USD
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkPrice3" name="checkPrice3" style="margin-top:2px;width:16px;height:16px;vertical-align:middle;" onclick="onPriceCheckChanged(this)" />
        <label for="checkPrice3" style="color: #626363;vertical-align:middle;">3 months rent</label>
    </span>
    <div>
        <script type='text/javascript' id='validate_Price3Raw'>/*<![CDATA[*/ mqGlobal.AddOnReady(function() {V.push(['Price3Raw',10,'Invalid price format. Please enter number',CheckProductPrice]);});mqGlobal.AddOnReady(function() {V.push(['Price3Raw',10,'Invalid price',CheckProductSubscribePriceValue]);}); /*]]>*/</script>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="margin-bottom:5px;">
    <div class="inputWrapper" style="width:100px;display:inline-block;*display:inline;*zoom:1;*margin-right:5px;line-height:22px;vertical-align:middle;">
        <input data-old="" id="Price2Raw" name="Price2Raw" style="text-align: right; padding-right:2px;" type="text" value="0.00" />
    </div>

    <span id="Price2Additional" style="color:#626363;display:inline-block;*display:inline;*zoom:1;line-height:22px;vertical-align:middle;">
        USD
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkPrice2" name="checkPrice2" style="margin-top:2px;width:16px;height:16px;vertical-align:middle;" onclick="onPriceCheckChanged(this)" />
        <label for="checkPrice2" style="color: #626363;vertical-align:middle;">6 months rent</label>
    </span>
    <div>
        <script type='text/javascript' id='validate_Price2Raw'>/*<![CDATA[*/ mqGlobal.AddOnReady(function() {V.push(['Price2Raw',10,'Invalid price format. Please enter number',CheckProductPrice]);});mqGlobal.AddOnReady(function() {V.push(['Price2Raw',10,'Invalid price',CheckProductSubscribePriceValue]);}); /*]]>*/</script>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="margin-bottom:5px;">
    <div class="inputWrapper" style="width:100px;display:inline-block;*display:inline;*zoom:1;*margin-right:5px;line-height:22px;vertical-align:middle;">
        <input data-old="" id="Price1Raw" name="Price1Raw" style="text-align: right; padding-right:2px;" type="text" value="0.00" />
    </div>

    <span id="Price1Additional" style="color:#626363;display:inline-block;*display:inline;*zoom:1;line-height:22px;vertical-align:middle;">
        USD
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkPrice1" name="checkPrice1" style="margin-top:2px;width:16px;height:16px;vertical-align:middle;" onclick="onPriceCheckChanged(this)" />
        <label for="checkPrice1" style="color: #626363;vertical-align:middle;">1 year rent</label>
    </span>
</div>
<div>
```

And this is javascript snippet from that link above:

```
function onPriceCheckChanged(priceCheck)
{
    var readonly = !priceCheck;
    var any = readonly || priceCheck.id == "priceFree";
    var checked = readonly || (any ? !priceCheck.checked : priceCheck.checked);
    var anyChecked = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        var pc = $("checkPrice" + (i || ""));
        if(any || pc.id == priceCheck.id)
        {
            if(!readonly)
                pc.checked = checked;
            checkPriceCheck(pc);
        }
        if(pc.checked)
            anyChecked = true;
    }
    if(!readonly && priceCheck.id !== "priceFree" && priceCheck.checked)
    {
        $("priceFree").checked = false;
    }
    var actObj = $('MaxActivations');
    var actObjD = $('MaxActivationsDisabled');
    var feeObj = $('AffilationFee');
    if(!anyChecked)
    {
        if(feeObj)
        {
            oldFee = feeObj.value;
            feeObj.value = 0;
            feeObj.disabled = "disabled";
            feeObj.readonly = "readonly";
        }
        if(actObj && actObjD)
        {
            oldAct = actObj.value;
            actObj.value = 10;
            actObj.style.display = "none";
            actObjD.style.display = "inline";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(feeObj)
        {
            feeObj.value = oldFee;
            feeObj.disabled = null;
            feeObj.readonly = null;
        }
        if(actObj && actObjD)
        {
            actObj.value = oldAct;
            actObj.style.display = "inline";
            actObjD.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

*Update 1

1. The first checkbox when checked then another options will disabled (it's default)

[image]

2. The first checkbox when uncheck then another options will be enable to check or uncheck and can fill the number fields too

[image]

3. The another options when one or more checkbox is uncheck then it can fill the number fields too

[image]

*Update 2

Here's the full source code from original site: gist.github.com/pije76/6cb0a03d705b56f145cd0014da480f73

*Update 3

Here's the modified code from Sally's answer:

```
(function($)
{
    $('input[type="number"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $(':checkbox#field_fm78o-0').on('click', function()
    {
        $(':checkbox[id^="field_masaberlaku_"]').prop('checked', !this.checked).change();
    });

    $(':checkbox[id^="field_masaberlaku_"]').on('change', function()
    {
        var cont = $(this).closest('div.frm_form_field').prev('div.frm_form_field');
        cont.find('input[type="number"]').prop('disabled', this.disabled || !this.checked);
        $(':checkbox#field_fm78o-0').prop("checked", false);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

*Update 4

The 3 steps:

```
// 1. Disable the Price field when the "Gratis" field is checked but keep enable the "masa berlaku" fields so user can check it. (default)
    $('input[type="number"]').prop('disabled', true);

// 2a. When the "Gratis" field is unchecked then checked all the "masa berlaku" fields.
    $(':checkbox#field_fm78o-0').on('click', function()
    {
        $(':checkbox[id^="field_masaberlaku_"]').prop('checked', !this.checked).change();
    });

// 2b. When one or more the "masa berlaku" fields is checked then user can fill the Price field that have relationship with that field and also disable the other Price fields.
    $(':checkbox[id^="field_masaberlaku_"]').on('change', function()
    {
        var cont = $(this).closest('div.frm_form_field').prev('div.frm_form_field');
        cont.find('input[type="number"]').prop('disabled', this.disabled || !this.checked);
        $(':checkbox#field_fm78o-0').prop("checked", false);
    });

// 3. When the "Gratis" field is checked again then go back the behaviour to step 1 again (default). 
// I am stuck on this step when pass the step 1 & 2 then I can not check the Gratis field again and I am not sure how to get this step.
```

Comment: To be able to help you, give a valid link. Getting the 500 error. Or add another link with the same desired behavior.

Comment: I am sorry for getting 500 error, I forget that site need to register as private user.
Here's the site that I try to build with same desired behavior: http://korexindo.com/k-market/form-k-market/
You can see at the bottom of form on word: "Harga"

Comment: Can you show the generated source/HTML for [that "Price" element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhZkO.jpg)? Or better, create a public test form with those conditional fields.

Comment: Here's the full source code: https://gist.github.com/pije76/6cb0a03d705b56f145cd0014da480f73

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I don't have Formidable Forms pro/paid version which comes with the [conditional fields](https://formidableforms.com/features/conditional-logic-wordpress-forms/) support; but I posted this "generic" jQuery/JavaScript solution since you still have not accepted any answers.. and I hope it helps you.*

So I'm giving you just the script; you can put it in the theme footer (before `</body>` and don't forget the `<script>` and `</script>` tags) or place it in an external `.js` file:

*UPDATE Jul 27th 2019: You can find the script in the following snippet.*

That is, however, specific to the markup/HTML of the Harga/Price section as it is currently on the site. But you can basically use the above code as a reference for similar sections in the form. And here's a working [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RXopNb/left?editors=1010#0):

```js
(function($){
  // Define the selectors/variables; be as specific as possible.
  var gratis = $(':checkbox#field_fm78o-0');
  var price_fields = $('.frm_form_field input[type="number"]');
  var masa_berlakus = $(':checkbox[id^="field_masaberlaku_"]');

  // On page load..
  price_fields.prop('disabled', true);  // disable the price fields
  masa_berlakus.prop('checked', false); // and uncheck the "masa berlaku" fields.

  // On click of the "Gratis" field..
  // Gratis checked: disable the price fields; uncheck the "masa berlaku" fields.
  // Gratis unchecked: enable the price fields; check the "masa berlaku" fields.
  gratis.on('change', function(){
    price_fields.prop('disabled', this.checked);
    masa_berlakus.prop('checked', ! this.checked);
  });

  // On click of each "masa berlaku" field..
  // If checked: enable the price field; uncheck the "Gratis" field.
  // If unchecked: disable the price field.
  masa_berlakus.on('change', function(){
    var cont = $(this).closest('div.frm_form_field')
      .prev('div.frm_form_field');

    cont.find('input[type="number"]')
      .prop('disabled', ! this.checked);

    if (this.checked) {
      gratis.prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<!-- WordPress still uses jQuery v1.12.4 -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="frm_field_16_container" class="frm_form_field form-field frm_left_container frm_first frm_third horizontal_radio">
  <div id="field_fm78o_label" class="frm_primary_label">Harga:
    <span class="frm_required"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="frm_opt_container" aria-labelledby="field_fm78o_label" role="group">
    <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_16-8-0"><label for="field_fm78o-0"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[16][]" id="field_fm78o-0" value="Gratis" checked="checked" data-sectionid="8" data-frmval="[&quot;Gratis&quot;]" data-invmsg="Harga: is invalid" /> Gratis</label></div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Hidden inputs here -->
<div id="frm_field_18_container" class="frm_form_field form-field frm_left_container frm_first frm_third">
  <label for="field_5ust4" id="field_5ust4_label" class="frm_primary_label">Harga1:
    <span class="frm_required"></span>
  </label>
  <input type="number" id="field_5ust4" name="item_meta[18]" value="" data-sectionid="8" placeholder="Rp. 0,00" data-invmsg="unlimited price is invalid" min="1" max="99999999999" step="1"/>
</div>
<div id="frm_field_19_container" class="frm_form_field form-field frm_left_container frm_third horizontal_radio">
  <div id="field_masaberlaku_1_label" class="frm_primary_label">masa berlaku:
    <span class="frm_required"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="frm_opt_container" aria-labelledby="field_masaberlaku_1_label" role="group">
    <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_19-8-0"><label for="field_masaberlaku_1-0"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[19][]" id="field_masaberlaku_1-0" value="Tanpa batas" checked="checked" data-sectionid="8" data-frmval="[&quot;Tanpa batas&quot;]" data-invmsg="masa berlaku: is invalid" /> Tanpa batas</label></div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Hidden inputs here -->
<div id="frm_field_20_container" class="frm_form_field form-field frm_left_container frm_first frm_third">
  <label for="field_5wbs3" id="field_5wbs3_label" class="frm_primary_label">Harga2:
    <span class="frm_required"></span>
  </label>
  <input type="number" id="field_5wbs3" name="item_meta[20]" value="" data-sectionid="8" placeholder="Rp. 0,00" data-invmsg="unlimited price is invalid" min="1" max="99999999999" step="1"/>
</div>
<div id="frm_field_21_container" class="frm_form_field form-field frm_left_container frm_third horizontal_radio">
  <div id="field_masaberlaku_2_label" class="frm_primary_label">masa berlaku:
    <span class="frm_required"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="frm_opt_container" aria-labelledby="field_masaberlaku_2_label" role="group">
    <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_21-8-0"><label for="field_masaberlaku_2-0"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[21][]" id="field_masaberlaku_2-0" value="Sewa 1 bulan" checked="checked" data-sectionid="8" data-frmval="[&quot;Sewa 1 bulan&quot;]" data-invmsg="masa berlaku: is invalid" /> Sewa 1 bulan</label></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="frm_field_22_container" class="frm_form_field form-field frm_left_container frm_first frm_third">
  <label for="field_yjuqd" id="field_yjuqd_label" class="frm_primary_label">Harga3:
    <span class="frm_required"></span>
  </label>
  <input type="number" id="field_yjuqd" name="item_meta[22]" value="" data-sectionid="8" placeholder="Rp. 0,00" data-invmsg="unlimited price is invalid" min="1" max="99999999999" step="1"/>
</div>
<div id="frm_field_23_container" class="frm_form_field form-field frm_left_container frm_third horizontal_radio">
  <div id="field_masaberlaku_3_label" class="frm_primary_label">masa berlaku:
    <span class="frm_required"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="frm_opt_container" aria-labelledby="field_masaberlaku_3_label" role="group">
    <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_23-8-0"><label for="field_masaberlaku_3-0"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[23][]" id="field_masaberlaku_3-0" value="Sewa 3 bulan" checked="checked" data-sectionid="8" data-frmval="[&quot;Sewa 3 bulan&quot;]" data-invmsg="masa berlaku: is invalid" /> Sewa 3 bulan</label></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="frm_field_24_container" class="frm_form_field form-field frm_left_container frm_first frm_third">
  <label for="field_mjy2z" id="field_mjy2z_label" class="frm_primary_label">Harga4:
    <span class="frm_required"></span>
  </label>
  <input type="number" id="field_mjy2z" name="item_meta[24]" value="" data-sectionid="8" placeholder="Rp. 0,00" data-invmsg="unlimited price is invalid" min="1" max="99999999999" step="1"/>
</div>
<div id="frm_field_25_container" class="frm_form_field form-field frm_left_container frm_third horizontal_radio">
  <div id="field_masaberlaku_4_label" class="frm_primary_label">masa berlaku:
    <span class="frm_required"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="frm_opt_container" aria-labelledby="field_masaberlaku_4_label" role="group">
    <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_25-8-0"><label for="field_masaberlaku_4-0"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[25][]" id="field_masaberlaku_4-0" value="Sewa 6 bulan" checked="checked" data-sectionid="8" data-frmval="[&quot;Sewa 6 bulan&quot;]" data-invmsg="masa berlaku: is invalid" /> Sewa 6 bulan</label></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="frm_field_26_container" class="frm_form_field form-field frm_left_container frm_first frm_third">
  <label for="field_c41ii" id="field_c41ii_label" class="frm_primary_label">Harga5:
    <span class="frm_required"></span>
  </label>
  <input type="number" id="field_c41ii" name="item_meta[26]" value="" data-sectionid="8" placeholder="Rp. 0,00" data-invmsg="unlimited price is invalid" min="1" max="99999999999" step="1"/>
</div>
<div id="frm_field_27_container" class="frm_form_field form-field frm_left_container frm_third horizontal_radio">
  <div id="field_masaberlaku_5_label" class="frm_primary_label">masa berlaku:
    <span class="frm_required"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="frm_opt_container" aria-labelledby="field_masaberlaku_5_label" role="group">
    <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_27-8-0"><label for="field_masaberlaku_5-0"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[27][]" id="field_masaberlaku_5-0" value="Sewa 1 tahun" checked="checked" data-sectionid="8" data-frmval="[&quot;Sewa 1 tahun&quot;]" data-invmsg="masa berlaku: is invalid" /> Sewa 1 tahun</label></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank u for your answer @sally-cj, I modified your code at Update 3 (I can not paste that code here cause limited character) but it can not check the "Gratis" checkbox again when other checkboxes is checked. Can you fix it please, and I will accept your answer.

Comment: And sorry, I wasn't really paying attention to the referenced website... (mql5.com).

Answer (score 5):

@pije Well if you're using Formidable then you need to employ Conditional Fields. This will allow you to trigger a show/hide of further fields depending on previously selected/checked fields: Their documentation is pretty solid for this: https://formidableforms.com/knowledgebase/using-conditional-logic/